# Custom embed command not working (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

So I'm writing this custom embed command for my discord.py bot. The bot asks a few questions then send a custom embed with the variables that the user specifies. The bot asks the first question and after i input the first variable/text, it stops responding.

Full code:

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['custom', 'cembed'])
    async def customembed(self,ctx):
      questions = ["What should be the name of the embed?", "What should be the desc","What is the colour of the embed?"]
      answers = []
      def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel 
      
      for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)
        msg=""
        try:
          msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time, please be quicker next time!")
          return
        else:
          answers.append(msg.content)

      title = answers[1]
      desc = answers[2]
      colour = answers[3]

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}", description = f"{desc}", color = colour)
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed)
```

I assume that the try block is at fault here:

```py
      for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)
        msg=""
        try:
          msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time, please be quicker next time!")
          return
        else:
          answers.append(msg.content)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

P.S I just created my SO account day so I'm pretty new to all of this, sorry if I say or do something wrong

Update:
I fixed some of the code that you guys suggested i'd change, but it still wouldn't say anything after sending the first question. Weird.

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['custom', 'cembed'])
    async def customembed(self,ctx):
      questions = ["What should be the name of the embed?", "What should be the desc", "What is the colour of the embed?"]
      answers = []
      def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel 
      
      for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)
        msg=""
        try:
          msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time, please be quicker next time!")
          return
        else:
          answers.append(msg.content)

      title = answers[0]
      desc = answers[1]
      colour = answers[2]

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}", description = f"{desc}", color = int(colour))
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed)
```

[Here's what I get](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/849020748579864616/854103306879107132/unknown.png).

Update 2:

I got it to register the first question/answer AND the second question/answer, but it doesnt register the color variable. I had to change `await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)` to `await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)`

Update 3:
I fixed it! I had to change `int(colour) to` int(color, 16)`. Now it works and uses all the variables that i want it to use, thanks to whoever helped me.

Here's the working code:

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['custom', 'cembed'])
    async def customembed(self,ctx):
      questions = ["What should be the name of the embed?", "What should be the desc", "What is the colour of the embed?"]
      answers = []
      def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel 
      
      for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)
        msg=""
        try:
          msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time, please be quicker next time!")
          return
        else:
          answers.append(msg.content)

      title = answers[0]
      desc = answers[1]
      colour = answers[2]

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}", description = f"{desc}", color = int(colour, 16))
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: *PS: Indexes start at 0, not 1*, other than that the code works for me (the issue might be that you didn't define `client` I think you're looking for `self.client` as you're within a cog)

Comment: i changed the index numbers and used `self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)` yet it still stops responding after the first question, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you fixed it, you should add the fix as an answer to your own question instead of editing it in. But glad you got it!